Creating a Chrome bookmark to automate a web PHP search
I am an user in some forum, and I want to create a bookmark for searching my past messages. To do so, you can open an advanced search link whose address is as follows (identifiable words have been hidden in <>):
<webpage>.com/<string>/search.php?searchuser=<my_user_id>

In that advanced search page, there is a "search" button at the bottom which launches the search and redirects me to a new link which includes a list of all my past messages and whose address is:
<webpage>.com/<string>/search.php?searchid=<some_number>

Therefore the above link merely redirects me to the advanced search page: I still need to click on the search buttom.
Is there a way to create a Chrome bookmark which automates the whole process? When I try to hover over the search button I am not getting any adress/link name.
The forum has been written using vBulletin (see comments below this post).
Note: although PHP programming questions are out of scope in this forum, this is not really a programming question. If better suited, this can be migrated to Stack Overflow.

It's neither SU nor SO question indeed. That would be a question for web app SE, but since you are not providing a web app, then not really... You could at least check and give us the forum script  in question, if it's not custom.

@Destroy666 pardon my ignorance, what are you referring to by "forum script"?

You mentioned a forum, no? What is it running on? A.k.a. software visible in footer or detectable in many ways, often referred to as "forum script" by forum users.

@Destroy666 by looking at the source code I think this is HTML, below is the first few lines of the source code from the home webpage: ```


```

Ok, so vBulletin. Please edit that in.

I can't reproduce it on latest vBulletin. So you're eaither adding wrong page to bookmarks (should be result one) or it's some old version of it.
